# How to remove an html element that it loaded after click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose we have a button in a HTML page. When I click on this button other HTML code from third party is loaded and I want to delete a component:

```
<a component="post/edit" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
    <span class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span> Edit
</a>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[component="post/edit"]', function() {
    var tid = 3;
    socket.emit('plugins.connectschedulatopic.getTopic', { 'tid': tid }, function(err, topic) {
        if (topic) {
            if (Date.now() > topic.timestamp) {
                console.log("FA FACALENDAR DA ELIMINARE");
                // code is executed up to here but when execute the next line the program doesn't delete element
                $('li[data-format="calendar"]').remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I think it is a problem of loading. Anyone can help me?

Comment: please make a JSFIDDLE with your code.

Comment: `console.log($('li[data-format="calendar"]'))` to check if your selector matches anything